# Relative Padding in Floated Elements: why does it work this way?

Tags: html, css

So I understand how to deal with the following question, but I'd really like to understand the underlying logic behind **why** this happens.

This scenario assumes you have 2 floated divs (one to the left and one to the right) that each take up 50% of the page.  If you set them up like so:

```
.left {
    background-color: #CCFFCC;
    width: 50%;
    float: left;
}

.right {
    background-color: #FFFFCC;
    width: 50%;
    float: right;
}
```

The divs are right next to one another and take up 100% of the page total.

However if you set them up like this:

```
.left {
    background-color: #CCFFCC;
    width: 50%;
    float: left;
    padding: 10%;
}

.right {
    background-color: #FFFFCC;
    width: 50%;
    float: right;
    padding: 10%;
}
```

The right element slides under the left one.

I know several ways to deal with this, including the box-sizing property, but what I'd **REALLY** like to know is why this happens.

According to the box model, the padding gets added to the **inside** of a div (which I thought would leave the overall size of the div the same as before), but adding padding is actually increasing the **overall** size of a div.

Any help would be really appreciated!

**edit:**
I see now that the actual width =

```
width + padding + border = actual width of an element
```

(*thanks NewsletterPoll!*)

I guess I just had a fundamental misunderstanding about how padding gets applied. My intuitive response was to assume that padding will basically subtract from the content area, but that's not how it works, I see now.

This may be something nobody can answer, but why is it that it's built so unintuitively like this? Basically width =/= the actual width, which seems confusing. I'm wondering if way back in the day padding was added as an afterthought, or if possibly they just created it this way to begin with?

That might be more of a critique of CSS as a whole and how it was developed, and may not have any actual reasoning behind it.  But if there **IS** a reason that it doesn't subtract to the content area, that could be interesting or helpful to know.

Comment: By default, the width and height of an element is calculated like this:

width + padding + border = actual width of an element
height + padding + border = actual height of an element  

This means: When you set the width/height of an element, the element often appear bigger than you have set (because the element's border and padding are added to the element's specified width/height).  http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_box-sizing.asp

Comment: Because W3C designed it in an usually non-intuitive way. Microsoft did it the intuitive way. Eventually, W3C added `box-sizing` to let authors decide.

Answer (score 0):

This happens because the default value for `box-sizing` is `content-box`.
When in this box-sizing mode, the width is computed as:

```
actual width = width + padding + border
```

So your element with CSS properties

```
width: 50%;
padding: 10%;
```

Ends up being 70% wide (10 + 50 + 10).

```
| 10% |    50%    | 10% |
```

and 2 elements that are 70% wide do not fit next to each other.

---

From [MDN : box-sizing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing) :

> **content-box**
>
> This is the default style as specified by the CSS standard. The width and height properties are measured including only the content, but not the padding, border or margin. Note: ***Padding, border & margin will be outside of the box e.g. IF .box {width: 350px}; THEN you apply {border: 10px solid black;} RESULT {rendered in the browser} .box {width: 370px;}***

---

Your original statement is actually correct:

> "According to the box model, the padding gets added to the inside of a div"

The padding *IS* inside the div, however the `width` CSS property when in `box-sizing:content-box` is telling the browser what the width of the 'content area' inside the div should be. Then the actual div is the combination of the padding, border, and content area. (in other words, you are saying the content area is 50% wide, not that the div is 50% wide)